# undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, methods, null

**Can someone help me with this error?**

> NoMethodError in Posts#create
>
> Showing C:/Users/User/Documents/website/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb
>   where line #24 raised:
>
> undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass
>
> Extracted source (around
>   line #24):
>
> 23:     <%= f.label :categoria
>   %>
>  24:       <%= f.select :categoria_id, @categoria.collect { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] } %>
>
> Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/new.html.erb

My _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :titulo %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :titulo %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :conteudo %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :conteudo %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :categoria %><br />
     <%= f.select :categoria_id, @categoria.collect { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] } %>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.json
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @categoria = Categorium.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @categoria = Categorium.all
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `Categorium` model? It seems like `@categoria` is returning `nil` despite the fact that it's clearly being created from your database in the `posts#new` method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `new` action is defining `@categoria`, which is then used in your view.

If your `create` action creates an invalid object, it will re-render the `new` view which still expects `@categoria` to be defined, but it is not.

You will need to define the instance variable in both your `new` and `create` actions.

Comment: I see it now. He did a `render` instead of a `redirect_to`. Is this to preserve form content?

Comment: Yes, it's to keep the submitted form data to re-render it, as well as keeping error messages for display. If he was to redirect back to new, all you would get would be an empty form with possibly a flash message. Not very nice user experience.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.select :categoria_id, options_for_select(@categoria, :name, :id), :required => true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where's your create action?  You have defined a new action but no create action in your controller.  The create action is what will save your object.

Comment: create isn't the missing method. @categoria is returning nil.

Comment: Yes, @categoria is nil, but the bigger problem is that there's no object being saved.  I should have asked also if `Categorium` had existing values as well though...

Comment: Really? He must have added the create method to the code after you posted then. It's there now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define **@categoria = Categoria.all** instance variable  in both new, create, edit, update actions in your controller.

Answer (score -1):

Have you created any `categoria` yet? That would be the only reason I can think of why `@categoria` would return nil in your view.