# Ruby on Rails 4.2.6 Undefined Method page_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, content-management-system

This is the error that I'm getting: undefined method `page_id' for #Page:0x0000000b2c1e28.

Showing C:/Users/eiria/Sites/simple_cms/app/views/sections/_form.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `page_id' for #
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/sections/new.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/Users/eiria/Sites/simple_cms

I'm trying to nest Sections inside Pages for my Content Management System.

This is my Sections form:

```
<%= error_messages_for(@section) %>

<table summary="Section form fields">
    <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:page_id, "Page") %></th>
        <td><%= f.select(:page_id, @pages.map {|s| [s.name, s.id]}) %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:name) %></th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:position) %></th>
        <td><%= f.select(:position, 1..@section_count) %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:visible) %></th>
        <td><%= f.select(:visible, {"Visible" => 1, "Hidden" => 2}) %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:content_type) %></th>
        <td><%= f.select(:content_type, ['text', 'HTML']) %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:content) %></th>
        <td><%= f.text_area(:content, :size => '40x10') %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my Sections controller:

```
class SectionsController < ApplicationController
  layout "admin"

  before_action :confirm_logged_in
  before_action :find_page

  def index
    @sections = @page.sections.sorted
    @subject = @page.subject
  end

  def show
    @section = Section.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @section = Section.new({:page_id => @page.id, :name => "Default"})
    @pages = Page.order('position ASC')
    @section_count = Section.count + 1
  end

  def create
    @section = Section.new(section_params)

    if @section.save
      flash[:notice] = "Section created successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index', :page_id => @page.id)
    else
      @pages = Page.order('position ASC')
      @section_count = Section.count + 1
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def 
    @section = Section.find(params[:id])
    @pages = Page.order('position ASC')
    @section_count = Section.count
  end

  def update
    @section = Section.find(params[:id])

    if @section.update_attributes(section_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Section updated successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @section.id, :page_id => @page.id)
    else
      @section = Section.find(params[:id])
      @pages = Page.order('position ASC')
      @section_count = Section.count
      render('')
    end
  end

  def delete
    @section = Section.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    section = Section.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Section '#{section.name}' destroyed succsessfully."
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end

  private
    def section_params
      params.require(:section).permit(:page_id, :name, :permalink, :position, :visible, :content_type, :content)
    end

    def find_page
      if params[:page_id]
        @page = Page.find(params[:page_id])
        @subject = @page.subject
      end
    end
end
```

Section model:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :page
    has_many :section_edits
    has_many :editors, :through => :section_edits, :class_name => "AdminUser"

    CONTENT_TYPES = ['text', 'HTML']

    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 255

    validates_inclusion_of :content_type, :in => CONTENT_TYPES,
    :message => "must be one of: #{CONTENT_TYPES.join(', ')}"
    validates_presence_of :content

    scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true) }
    scope :invisible, lambda { where(:visible => false) }
    scope :sorted, lambda { order("sections.position ASC") }
    scope :newest_first, lambda { order("sections.created_at DESC") }
end
```

Page model:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subject
    has_many :sections
    has_and_belongs_to_many :editors, :class_name => "AdminUser"

    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 255

    validates_presence_of :permalink
    validates_length_of :permalink, :within => 3..255
    validates_uniqueness_of :permalink

    scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true) }
    scope :invisible, lambda { where(:visible => false) }
    scope :sorted, lambda { order("pages.position ASC") }
    scope :newest_first, lambda { order("pages.created_at DESC") }
end
```

I don't see why it says undefined method page_id for line 6, while the same is used for line 5 but theres apparently nothing wrong there...

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S: This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please forgive me for any obvious mistakes. This question is almost completely identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278758/nomethoderror-in-sectionsedit-similar-issue-to-other), but my problem is creating a new section and not  it.

Comment: Could you include the models for Page and Section as well?

Comment: @ConnorCMcKee Models are added now.

Comment: I think You should read about nested forms: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev Hmmm... The thing is however, that I'm following a tutorial, so changing it will kind of break it..

Comment: The section form is not complete i think you can put the complete code. Looks like it's a form for a Page model.. and its try to get page_id from a page.. where is the variable f coming from?

Comment: I have new.html.erb that uses the form as a partial: <%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index', :page_id => @page.id}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="sections new">
 <h2>Create Section</h2>
 <%= form_for(:page, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
  <%= render(:partial => "sections/form", :locals => {:f => f}) %>

  <div class="form-buttons">
   <%= submit_tag("Create Section") %>
  </div>

 <% end %>
</div>

Comment: may be you wanted form_for(:section. :url.....form for :page will use @page

Comment: @FreeLine can i see yr `new.html.erb` file how do you call it ?

Comment: @7urkm3n I already posted my new.html.erb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see something like `undefined method 'page_id'`, where the method is a database column name, it usually means the column is missing from the database table---most often because you haven't yet run the appropriate migration.

In your case, it's not because you haven't run migrations, but because Rails is looking in the wrong table! Note that you are calling `page_id` on a `Page`, but it should be a `Section`:

```
undefined method `page_id' for #Page:0x0000000b2c1e28.
```

You don't show your `form_for` in the view, but you should make sure it is `form_for @section` and not `form_for @page`.

Also, the reason it gets past line 5 is because `f.label` doesn't need to call the `page_id` method, but `f.select` does (to get the current value).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try fixing it tomorrow (on phone atm). I can't believe I didn't notice that... I guess I forgot to change it when I copy pasted the forms. You're probably right, I'll mark your answer as correct if it works. Thx